# Viewpager like Home screen with drag rearrange and swipe down to delete

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

I have started working on making a simple launcher app. I have already gone through many posts and source code of various launchers but I am really stuck at the home screen thing. I just want to create a simple view pager and on long click of it I want it to behave like android stock launcher where user can drag and drop screens to rearrange it and may delete it by swiping down to the cross button.

I am really confused as there is no proper documentation of how things happening in android stock launcher

Please tell me how to achieve this properly. If anyone has extracted that code and give it to me it will be a great help. Links are appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The standard home screen is implemented as a single large view, with each screen being a child view. Each of those individual screens then lays out icons and app widgets according the grid appropriate for the device.

The way the swiping behavior works is by overriding onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent. It's tricky because there are so many things that a touch could be doing: the user could be tapping on an icon, swiping to the next screen, or starting a long-press. When you implement one of these behaviors, you have to make sure you don't get in the way of another one.

Once the user is doing a long-press, your launcher app enters a different mode, and the event processing behaves differently in this mode. That is, it implements the standard drag-and-drop behavior. This is tricky too.

I spent two years of my life working on the home screen app for a major device manufacturer. It's complicated, and I'd recommend that you have a good reason for diving into the project.

Comment: I have only a month to do this :'( . Can you tell me if some one has extracted or any good explanation ?

Comment: There might be some example source code out there, I have no idea. If you don't fine any, then my recommendation is to start simple. Start with a single screen that puts app icons on a 4x4 grid, and when the user clicks on one, it launches the app. Then add a row of fixed icons at the bottom. Then add a menu button, and an app menu screen. Then add multiple screens.

Comment: hi can you please explain to me how to add shortcut from all apps to workspace in Launcher3?, here my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410875/drag-and-drop-icons-to-home-screen